# Jenkins and maven npanday builds failed

Tags: .net, maven, continuous-integration, jenkins

**[UPDATE AND SOLUTIONS ARE ON MY RESPONSE BELOW]**

I am using npanday, a project to build .net projects using maven.
After load of steps I have figured out how to compile/install some projects using maven.

This work just right on my command console or visual studio, but once jenkins try to compile it maven fail to build it...

*Following is the failure output from Jenkins:*

> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty
> message : Failed to
>   execute goal
>   org.apache.npanday.plugins:NPanday.Plugin.Settings.JavaBinding:1.5.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT:generate-settings
>   (default-generate-settings) on project ConsoleApplication400:
>   NPANDAY-115-010: Error on resolving plugin artifact(s)
> cause :
>   NPANDAY-115-010: Error on resolving plugin artifact(s)
> Stack trace
>   : 
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed
>   to execute goal
>   org.apache.npanday.plugins:NPanday.Plugin.Settings.JavaBinding:1.5.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT:generate-settings
>   (default-generate-settings) on project ConsoleApplication400:
>   NPANDAY-115-010: Error on resolving plugin artifact(s)
>    at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
>    at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
>  at
>   org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:79)
>  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>  at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
>   at
>   org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
>  at
>   hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:98)
>    at
>   hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:64)
>    at
>   hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
>     at
>   hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
>  at
>   hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
>   at
>   hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
> Caused by:
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: NPANDAY-115-010: Error
>   on resolving plugin artifact(s)
>   at
>   npanday.plugin.AbstractMojo.execute(AbstractMojo.java:189)
>    at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
>   ...
>   27 more
> Caused by:
>   org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could
>   not find artifact
>   org.apache.npanday.plugins:NPanday.Plugin.Settings:dll:1.5.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT
> Try
>   downloading the file manually from the project website.
> Then,
>   install it using the command: 
>     mvn install:install-file
>   -DgroupId=org.apache.npanday.plugins -DartifactId=NPanday.Plugin.Settings -Dversion=1.5.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=dotnet-maven-plugin -Dfile=/path/to/file
> Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
>     mvn
>   deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.apache.npanday.plugins
>   -DartifactId=NPanday.Plugin.Settings -Dversion=1.5.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=dotnet-maven-plugin -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
>   org.apache.npanday.plugins:NPanday.Plugin.Settings:dotnet-maven-plugin:1.5.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT
> from
>   the specified remote repositories:
>   central
>   (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true,
>   snapshots=false)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:219)
>  at
>   org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:157)
>  at
>   org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:525)
>  at
>   npanday.resolver.DefaultNPandayArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultNPandayArtifactResolver.java:77)
>   at
>   npanday.executable.impl.NetExecutableFactoryImpl.getPluginExecutable(NetExecutableFactoryImpl.java:396)
>   at
>   npanday.plugin.AbstractMojo.execute(AbstractMojo.java:173)
>    ... 29
>   more
> Caused by:
>   org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not
>   find artifact
>   org.apache.npanday.plugins:NPanday.Plugin.Settings:dll:1.5.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT
>  at
>   org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
>   at
>   org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
>  at
>   org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:193)
>   at
>   org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:286)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:213)
>  ...
>   34 more
> Caused by:
>   org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find
>   artifact
>   org.apache.npanday.plugins:NPanday.Plugin.Settings:dll:1.5.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT
>  at
>   org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:528)
>   ...
>   38 more
> channel stopped
> Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Is you configuration on the build server (jenkins) the same in particular repository manager (settings.xml file)?

Comment: i didn't get what you meant both jenkins and maven are on the same computer, also the configuration of maven plugin on jenkins point on the right maven_home and the right version. if there is a required configuration between the maven's settings.xml and jenkins config please enlight me. thanks

Comment: Hm. You wrote you have done packaging before but it looks one of its dependencies can be found? Have you defined to use a local repository in Jenkins?

Comment: the local maven repository list on jenkins configuration page have the default value of 'Default (~/.m2/repository)' , i have configured maven to use a local archiva repository, but still this can work on cmd.exe and from VS2010 [test,compile,install] goals, but not on Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

jenkins when he runs maven over the plugin he point on c:/.m2 by default, in the other hand maven point over C:/Users/UserDoc/.m2, if you use npanday he map the .net framework on file named npanday-settings.xml
all i had to do is to copy this mapping file to jenkins mavens repo "C:/.m2" folder.